# Backbone/Marionette - How to fetch collection data from an external server?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Is there a similar property to `urlRoot` for a collection?
My collection is currently set up as so:

```
Entities.Notifications = Entities.Collection.extend({
    model: Entities.Notification,
    url: '/notifications'
});
```

`/notification` is appended to the domain name when fetching. How do I do something like:

```
Entities.Notifications = Entities.Collection.extend({
    model: Entities.Notification,
    url: 'https://www.differentdomain.com/notifications'
});
```

So it gets the data from a different source?

Comment: What is the result you get with `url: 'https://www.differentdomain.com/notifications'`?

Comment: It appends `/notifications` to the domain that the site uses, e.g. `https://www.actualdomain.com/notifications`

Comment: That is when you do `url: '/notifications'`, isn't it? What about the full URL?

Comment: Sorry, I meant it appends `https://www.differentdomain.com/notifications` to the domain that the site uses, e.g. `https://www.actualdomain.com/https://www.differentdomain.com/notifications`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [example from the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url), it looks like if you define URL as a function it shouldn't do the append, something like:

```
var Notes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   url: function() {
      return 'https://www.differentdomain.com/notifications';
   }
});
```